# SAS Pocket Reference

Tags: reference, sas

I'm looking for a SAS pocket reference that provides listings of SAS procedures/statements. I don't want detailed explanations of each procedure - just a list of the procedures and maybe a short description to jog one's memory. A sublist of the statements associated with each procedure would be helpful. Something along the lines of the O'Reilly "HTML and XHTML Pocket Reference" or the "CSS Pocket Reference", but for SAS, would be most beneficial. A physical book would be preferable, but an online resource which meets the criteria is also acceptable.

I currently have The Little SAS Book (by Delwiche and Slaughter), and it's a great resource, but it's not what I'm looking for in terms of a quick reference.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

Professional SAS Programmer's Pocket Reference (Paperback)
by Rick Aster

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-SAS-Programmers-Pocket-Reference/dp/1891957023](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1891957023)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is *exactly* what you are looking but here is a list of procedures [by name](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/allprodsproc/61917/HTML/default/a003135046.htm) or [by product](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/allprodsproc/61917/HTML/default/a003178332.htm).  Might be a handy bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a handy reference card in the doc but as the number of PROCs and options on the PROCs grew they were not practical.